# Parsing complex soap response

Tags: android, ksoap

I'm building my first application in android which consumes a wcf service.I'm using ksoap2 to parse the response.The response is actually an array of objects defined in C#.I did this following this really helpful [guide](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.gr/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html).Now my problem is that I need to consume a wcf service which returns again an array of objects in C# but this time some properties of these objects are other objects.So my question is how can I map the inner objects so that i can parse their properties?

In case I was unclear, I need to parse an object like this:

```
public class OutterObject {

     private InnerObject1 io1;
     private InnerObject2 io2;

}
```

Hope I was clear enough

Ok this is my simplified code i can't post all of it just the portion i think is at fault

```
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    Request.addProperty("connString",args.get(0));
    Request.addProperty("ClCode", args.get(1));
    Request.addProperty("TeCode", args.get(2));
    Request.addProperty("CourseDate", args.get(3));               



    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    envelope.addMapping(namespace, "SRV_WeekProgramm",newSRV_WeekProgramm().getClass());
    envelope.addMapping(namespace, "Course", new Course().getClass());
    envelope.addMapping(namespace, "StudentHours", new StudentHours().getClass());

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);    


    Course response = (Course)envelope.bodyIn; //this is where it crashes
```

and this is the thrown exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be cast to connectionInitializer.Course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that worked for me.
This is response message type from web service

```
  <message name="loginUserResponse">
     <part name="code" type="xsd:int"/>
     <part name="desc" type="xsd:string"/>
     <part name="user" type="tns:user"/>
  </message>
```

The method `loginUser` definition

```
<operation name="loginUser">
   <documentation>Login user.</documentation>
   <input message="tns:loginUserRequest"/>
   <output message="tns:loginUserResponse"/>
</operation>
```

Class `UserResponse` (Outter) contains `User` property:

```
public class UserResponse  implements KvmSerializable {
public int code;
public String desc;
public User user;
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0) {
    case 0:
        return code;
    case 1:
        return desc;
    case 2: 
        return user;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return null;
}

public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 3;
}
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "code";
        break;
    case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "desc";
        break;
    case 2:
        info.type = User.class;
        info.name = "user";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        this.code = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 1:
        this.desc = value.toString();
        break;
    case 2:
        this.user = (User) value;
    default:
        break;
    }       
}
  }
```

And the `User` class (Inner)

```
 public class User implements KvmSerializable  {
public int user_id;
public String username;
public String email;
public String password;

public User() {

}

public Object getProperty(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return user_id;
    case 1:
        return username;
    case 2:
        return email;
    case 3:
        return password;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 4;
}

public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "user_id";
        break;
    case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "username";
        break;
    case 2:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "email";
        break;
    case 3:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "password";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    if(null == value)
        value = "";
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        user_id = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 1:
        username = value.toString();
        break;
    case 2:
        email = value.toString();
        break;
    case 3:
        password = value.toString();
        break;
}
   }
```

**This is important**: make sure you register the keys for both outter class and inner class.

```
  envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "loginUserResponse", UserResponse.class);
  envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "user", User.class);
```

Finally, you can get the result by casting:

```
   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SERVER_URL); //open the requisition
   androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);// call
   UserResponse response = (UserResponse)envelope.bodyIn;
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Ok seems it will work for me too..I'll try it and get back to you..thank you for your time

Comment: Hi, i tried to do it but i get a casting error when i'm casting the envelope.bodyIn into the inner object....

Comment: Post your code and message type from web service into your question, I think maybe your key mapping cause error.

Comment: Please post the definition method, request, response (as my example)from your web service (go to your web service url:  http://yourhost...wsdl from web browser ), then I can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: well i've tried but it's really big and it wont be well formatted here.Can I send you an e-mail attached with the request and response?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ is a good tool for you. You should paste your code into pastebin and share link in your question, then other people face with this problem maybe find the answer.

Comment: ok turn I've written it all over again,now I'm able to parse it correctly.The problem arose beacause i had miswritten the way i get the objects off the list.Thank so much for your support i hope i didn't waste your time.