# kSOAP2: cast anyType to complexType in Java

Tags: java, web-services, ksoap2

I have a web service and I'm using kSOAP2 to send request and get response from this web service. I made class implements `KvmSerializable` in order to send complexTypes to the web service but when I'm getting a response I cannot cast it to my complexType. For example: I'm getting 'anyType' and I want to cast it to my class 'User' but then I'm getting a `ClassCastException`

> cannot cast SoapObject to class User.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks for any help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must register your class with Soap envelope, some thing like this:

```
  envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "user", User.class);
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12912334/719212) that worked for me.

Comment: In case of issues here, I used:

  envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "user", new User().getClass());